# Diophantine equation with "extra" conditions

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, linear-diophantine-equations

My question is how can I solve Diophantine equations with additional restrictions. For example, what about $x+2y+5z=40$ coupled with $x+y+z=20$ where $x,y,z>0$?

Answer (score 1):

The difference between any two integer solutions is an integer multiple of the cross product $(3,-4,1).$ By inspection, I can see that $(0,20,0)$ is a solution. Next
$$  (3, 16,1),  $$
$$  (6, 12,2)  $$
$$  (9, 8,3)  $$
$$  (12, 4,4)  $$

Comment: How do you get the operation $(3, -4, 1)$, and is it possible that others exist?

Comment: @drewjoe these are it. The vector $(3,-4,1)$ satisfies both $x+y+z = 0$ and $x+2y+5z = 0.$ We also have $\gcd(3,-4,1) = 1.$ Every solution is of the form $(0,20,0) + t (3,-4,1)$ with integer $t$

Answer (score 0):

$x+2y+5z=40$ and $x+y+z=20$ and $x,y,z > 0$

Subtracting you get $y + 4z = 20$, that is $y = 20-4z$

$y>0$ and $z>0$ implies $z \in \{1,2,3,4\}$.

Substituting $y=20-4z$ into $x+y+z=20$, we get $x=3z$.

So $x = 3z, \ y = 20-4z$, and  $z \in \{1,2,3,4\}$.